# Allow external Internet connection when also connected on VPN

Tags: vpn

I'm using Mac.

My company is using Checkpoint VPN client and every time I connect via VPN my external internet connection drops.

Is there a way I can solve this problem? I.e. keep external connection while also connected on VPN?

Comment: Talk with your company about it. Typically what you ask for is called split tunnel vpn. There may be reasons why they don't want that.

Comment: Split tunnel would mean that your machine either routes to Corp for servers in the Corp IP range, or directly to the public internet for all other IPs. The more common setup is that you can still access the public internet, but routed via the corp network. A remote VPN connection to your company should behave exactly the same as if you were in the office. Question: do you have public internet access while in the office, or is this something they are intentionally cutting off?

Comment: Basically; whether you *can* (ie is technically possible), and whether you *should* (ie violates corp IT policy or your employment contract) are two very different questions. You need to talk to your corp IT people, not some randos on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

A properly configured VPN should be working exactly like your system is functioning.

What you're asking for is a *split* connection. **Yes it is possible, but doing so is considered to be a security threat**.

Fundamentally you need a second layer 2 (ethernet) port. This can be done with either a real physical second connection, or a virtual second port on one physical device.

I encourage you to carefully consider your reasons.

Comment: Downvoted. While it may introduce security risks, it's not a security risk by itself, if properly handled. Furthermore, second port won't really help if the vpn daemon overwrites your routing table.

Comment: @vidarlo - Just so I understand, you're saying both *"It's not a security risk"* and *"It can't be done"*? I don't suppose the fact that I've done it would change your view?

Comment: I'm saying it can't be done *if* the vpn daemon overwrites your routing table. But what you can achieve by adding a second ethernet adapter can trivially be achieved by editing your routing table, or in a OS which supports it, using network namespaces.